# Responsive slanted div with background

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a slanted angle div but I can't make it responsive, when the screen gets bigger the layout breaks completely

here is what i've been working on so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEbWvG

```css
/* SCSS */

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slantedDivA{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skewY(-4deg);
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1366x768');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedDivA">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  content
</div>
```

i got this example: http://prntscr.com/gf6yy5

how can i do it and make it responsive? is it possible with only css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/t6L7n959/).

The slant div is responsive. In my case, I used pseudo element like `:after`. :)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slantedDivA{ width: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
font-size: 36px; 
padding: 10% 25px; 
background: gray; 
color: #fff; 
position: relative; }

.slantedDivA:after{ content: "";
border-left: 99.58vw solid gray;
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 43px solid transparent;
bottom: -43px;
position: absolute;
left: -10px; }
```

```html
    <div class="slantedDivA">
  <div class="test">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example there's a lot going on, much of it contributes nothing to the effect you are trying to achieve. If you just want to cut off a corner of a div, I think the easiest solution is the following: have a big box that is skewed a little with overflow hidden. Its child element is skewed by the same amount in the opposite direction. I think this will work more reliably than having big white rectangles hiding the underlying content.

Example:

```css
.cutout {
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  background: #eee;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cutout"><div class="content">text</div></div>
```